# How to make an else statement without looping through all items in the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to print one statement "Book not found" after searching a list of dictionaries with a for loop. But it prints out "Book not found" for each book that isn't the one I'm looking for.

Here is the relevant code

```
 for item in books_sorted:
     if item["title"] == search:
         print(item.get("title"), ",", item.get("author"))
         print("This book is in the collection")
     else:
         print("Book not found")`
```

I tried formatting it in a (for item in item) and I tried writing the exception outside the loop. I tried adding another if item not in statement. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: books_sorted Is a list of dictionaries and you want the dictionary where item["title"] == search?

Comment: Yes, that part works. What I dont want is for it to print "Book not found" for every dictionary in the list that is not == search.

Comment: Okay then my answer solves your problem

Comment: You've posted a few lines of code totally out of context, without any information about data types of variables, and expect us to help you solve a problem with it. That's not reasonable. See [ask] and [mre], and then [edit] your post. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you spend the time to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
else:
     print("Book not found")`
```

In each iteration of the loop, if

```
if item["title"] == search:
```

Doesn’t evaluate to `True`, the `else` statement is run.

Try this instead:

```
books_sorted: list[dict] = •••
search = •••

did_find: bool = False

for item in books_sorted:
    if item.get("title") == search:
         did_find = True
         print(“Title: ”, searchedValue.get("title"), "\n", “Author: ”, searchedValue.get("author"))
         print("This book is in the collection")
         break


if not did_find:
    print("Book not found")
```

Complexity: O(n) in the length of the list. 
Exceptions: None. `dict.get()` was used to avoid `KeyError` exceptions.

The assumption is that `books_sorted` and `search` are well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Because, You've given print('Book not found') inside the for loop. So it checks the title of each book in the list, and if title doesn't match, It gives the output as ;Book not found'. Here the above print statement should be given after the for loop is completed. To achieve this we can declare a variable with value 0(or False) and if the specific book is found, then the value can be changed to 1(or True). It is as simple as this:

```
c = 0 
for item in books_sorted:
    if item["title"] == search:
        c = 1
        print(item.get("title"), ",", item.get("author"))
        print("This book is in the collection")
        break
if c == 0:
    print("Book not found")`
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a flag `book_found` and to print at the end of the loop if not found.

```py
search = "Your Search Query"  # Replace with the book title you are searching for
book_found = False

for item in books_sorted:
    if item["title"] == search:
        print(item.get("title"), ",", item.get("author"))
        print("This book is in the collection")
        book_found = True
        break  # Exit the loop once a matching book is found

if not book_found:
    print("Book not found")
```

Another way is to filter your list on tile==search and to print not found if the result list is empty.